# How to fetch value from Static Resources

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, javascript, lightning-experience, static-resources

I am new to LWC and i have a Opportunity picklist StageName, i have stored stagename value changed to different language in static resource, now i want to fetch value from static resource and display it.
If i am using const keyword and displaying it then its working but i want to use static resource

js file

```
import { loadStyle, loadScript} from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import desc from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/Language";

import STAGE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.StageName';
export default class TranslateLang extends LightningElement {

connectedCallback(){
        if(this.template.isConnected){
            Promise.all([
                loadScript(this, dictionary + '/'),
            ])
            .then(() => {
                console.log('connected');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('error'+error);
            });
        }
    }

@wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: '012000000000000AAA',
        fieldApiName: '$fieldApi'
    })
    getPicklistValues ({ error, data }) {
        if(data){
            try{
                this.optionLabel = data.values.map( objPL => **dictionary[objPL.label]**  
                );
                console.log('this.optionLabel1 >>> '+ this.optionLabel);

            }
            catch(error){
                console.log('get pick value error >>> ',JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(error)));
            }
            
            }
```

this.optionLabel = data.values.map( objPL => **dictionary[objPL.label]**
here if we directly pass value of const then its displaying but if we use static resuorce then it is not displaying.

Answer (score 2):

Before you build a custom translation system, you should become familiar with the built-in features that may address your requirements.  Salesforce already provides support for translating picklist values (and other parts of the interface, in [Translation Workbench](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.workbench.htm&type=5).

For more static elements (like labels in a UI) which aren't defined elsewhere, you can create [Custom Labels](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cl_about.htm&type=5) which can also be translated in Translation Workbench, and which can be [used in LWCs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-labels.html?q=custom%20label).

As far as your existing approach, I think the issue is here:

```
loadScript(this, dictionary + '/'),
```

Try changing it to:

```
loadScript(this, dictionary),
```

The example in the docs is not great - it's showing how to load a specific file from within a Zip file static resource, but never explains that.  Since your static resource is not a zipfile, you don't need to append any path information.

**Edit to add**:  I don't see an import of your static resource.  If you have a static resource named 'dictionary', then you would need to import it like so:

```
import dictionary from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/dictionary';
```

Also, your static resource should be exporting something, and your code in the LWC should reference that export.  For example, in your code, you are referring to `dictionary[objPL.label]`, which implies that your static resource should be exporting `dictionary`.

Comment: Hey @jason, Thanks for quick reply, i know we can use  Custom Labels but in our requirement we do not want to use  Custom Labels so proceeded with this approach.

Comment: Hey @jason, Coming back to solution you provided its not working, i am getting null value in array this.optionLabel1 >>> ,,,,, Options WIRE >>> [null,null,null,null,null,null]

Comment: Hey @jason, Clark Can i know why i am getting null value, i am very new to lightning component can you help me this. Thanks in advance

Comment: @ShejalRaut  I've amended my answer